# Horizontal scrolling list view inside `SingleChildScrollView` in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make the attached layout in flutter but gives me error.
how do i put vertically scrollable `ListView` inside any container which can be horizontally scrollable which has parent vertically scrollable view `SingleChildScrollView`

[image]

this is my code:

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              S.of(context).fullfilmentheading,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .title
                  .merge(TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.3)),
            ),
          ),
          key: _con.scaffoldKey,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: config.App(context).appWidth(3),
                  vertical: config.App(context).appHeight(1)),
              //height: config.App(context).appHeight(100),
              child: Container(
//                color: Colors.green,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  // alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context,index){
                            return Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(data[index]),
                                SizedBox(width:config.App(context).appWidth(5)),
                                Text(data[index]),
                                SizedBox(width:config.App(context).appWidth(5)),
                                Text(data[index]),
                                SizedBox(width:config.App(context).appWidth(5)),
                                Text(data[index]),
                                SizedBox(width:config.App(context).appWidth(5)),
                                Text(data[index]),
                                SizedBox(width:config.App(context).appWidth(5)),
                                Text(data[index]),
                              ],
                            );
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ButtonTheme(
                      height: 50,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            side: BorderSide(
                                color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor)),
                        onPressed: () => {},
                        color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
                        // Colors.black,
                        child: Text(
                          "add".toUpperCase(),
//                        style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,// TextStyle(fontSize: 15)
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

this is the error i get:

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView file:///Users/shaikhawais/Projects/DTMerchantFlutter/lib/src/pages/fullfilment_details_page.dart:57:21
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1697:12)
#3      _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:512:13)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
#5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
#6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: _RenderSingleChildViewport#47dc5 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
```